# Get list of free numbers between X and Y In a circle way

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have a table with numbers between 1000 and 9999.

```
DECLARE @TempTable Table(index int,IsFree bit)
DECLARE @Max int,@Rows int
SET @Max=0
```

The `IsFree` set to true.

On day 1 a user can select number of row, for example 300,
The first 300 from 1 to 300 will set to false and the user will get all rows between 301-9999.

```
UPDATE @TempTable 
SET IsFree=0
WHERE index>=@Max 
AND index < @Max+@Rows
```

On day 2 the user can select 400 ,So i want that Rows 301 to 700 will set to false and the user will get rows 701 to 9999.

```
SELECT TOP 1 @Max=index
FROM @TempTable
WHERE IsFree=0
ORDER BY index
```

the first 300 can bet set to true but not necessary.

I mean that every day the max row index that has value of true + 1 , will be the first row to update false + the numbers of rows the user select.

My problem begin when i reach the end of the table, for example the max row index with true is 9990 and the user select 100, row 9991-9999 should set to false and all the rows that has value of true from 1 to 90 will set to false. the problem is how to set the next day, how to find that row 91 is the first row to update?

Comment: Is this an academic exercise or a real-world problem? If real-world, there may be better solutions to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: real world problem. what is your solution using sql server?

Comment: It probably needs a bit more thought that I can give at the moment, but why are you keeping the same table between days? Could you simply store the last-retrieved index each day, and use modulo (%) to bring it back round from 9999 to 1 again?

Comment: Also - what output do you need? Is `@TempTable` needed outside this function, or just `@Max`?

Answer (score 0):

when the index is 'behind' the start, you can use a 'notional index' if index + 10000 to order it to follow the end of the sequence

```
    DECLARE @TempTable Table([index] int,IsFree bit)
DECLARE @Max int,@Rows int
SET @Max=0

DECLARE @I int = 0;

WHILE @I <= 10000
BEGIN
    INSERT @TempTable VALUES(@I, 'true');
    SET @I = @I + 1;
END 

SET @MAX = 9900;
SET @ROWS  =1000;

--rows selected
WITH FREE AS (SELECT [index], 
                        IsFree, 
                        CASE WHEN [index] < @MAX THEN  [index] + 10000 ELSE [index] END as NotionalRow 
                        FROM @TempTable) 
    SELECT * FROM FREE WHERE NotionalRow>=@Max 
AND NotionalRow < @Max+@Rows ORDER BY NotionalRow; 


 --you can update over a WITH statement
WITH FREE AS (SELECT [index], 
                        IsFree, 
                        CASE WHEN [index] < @MAX THEN  [index] + 10000 ELSE [index] END as NotionalRow 
                        FROM @TempTable) 
    UPDATE FREE SET IsFree = 'false' WHERE NotionalRow>=@Max 
AND NotionalRow < @Max+@Rows ;
```